How to create a discord bot that sends notifications from a specific website to a discord channel?
I do have a website where I share some of my works, and I want people in discord get notified everytime when I post something new. And it has so many categories in site, and lots of roles in discord. I dont know how to do it automated.
I did make a bot that sends webhooks but I want to make it automated so I dont have to write all the things down over and over again. Thank you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
